# ICollectionView get specific object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm using a `ICollectionView` which holds a list of objects.
I need to get a specific object from it according to some
object property,is there a way to do that ?

For instance, the object is a `User` and I need to supply 
`name` to get this object. How would I do that?

```
private readonly ICollectionView usersCollectionView;

public MappingViewModelView()
{
    _UsersList = new ObservableCollection<User>
    {
        new User {Name = "Jhon"},

    };
    usersCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_UsersList);
    UsersCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get **`SourceCollection`** from **`ICollectionView`** instance and Cast it to your specific type (User in your case) and you can use LINQ extensions methods to get your result.

```
User user = usersCollectionView.SourceCollection.Cast<User>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Jhon");
```

**OR**

Use `OfType<T>` extension method:

```
User user = usersCollectionView.SourceCollection.OfType<User>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Jhon");
```

You have to add **`System.Linq`** namespace to use Cast and FirstOrDefault extension methods.

Comment: I didn't know about Cast<T>, seems handy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SourceCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.sourcecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the *ICollectionView* to get the *ObservableCollection*

```
User john = ((ObservableCollection<User>)usersCollectionView.SourceCollection).Where( x=> x.Name == "Jhon").FirstOrDefault();
```